# Set Hierarchy Level when applying addDataField in Power BI embedded analytics

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am embedding Power BI report in my web application using below libraries

powerbi-client v2.19.1 and powerbi-report-authoring v1.1.1

When we add Date fields in some data roles(for example if we add Date field in X axis for line chart) then we can see one option to change hierarchy level with in the visual settings itself (like below)
[image]

This settings is working fine for me(I was able to drill to any level using this button) but How can i do this by code?

Here I am looking for some solution to set drill down level when adding that data field to visual itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Microsoft Power BI.

You can submit your ideas in Fabric Community forum.

https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/